# Modal Window not scrolling till bottom

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a modal using css , html and JavaScript

The issue is it is not scrolling till the very bottom
For better reference i have added numbers 1 to 100 in the modal window
For some reason it scrolls only till 96 and doesn't scroll any further

Please someone suggest some changes in coding which can resolve this issue ( i am a newbie but i guess it might be something to be done in css)

Nevertheless i am attaching the codes here

```js
$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .pic {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 35%;
  }
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        1 <br> 2 <br> 3 <br> 4 <br> 5 <br> 6 <br> 7 <br> 8 <br> 9 <br> 10 <br> 11 <br> 12 <br> 13 <br> 14 <br> 15 <br> 16 <br> 17 <br> 18 <br> 19 <br> 20 <br> 21 <br> 22 <br> 23 <br> 24 <br> 25 <br> 26 <br> 27 <br> 28 <br> 29 <br> 30 <br> 31 <br> 32 <br>        33 <br> 34 <br> 35 <br> 36 <br> 37 <br> 38 <br> 39 <br> 40 <br> 41 <br> 42 <br> 43 <br> 44 <br> 45 <br> 46 <br> 47 <br> 48 <br> 49 <br> 50 <br> 51 <br> 52 <br> 53 <br> 54 <br> 55 <br> 56 <br> 57 <br> 58 <br> 59 <br> 60 <br> 61 <br> 62 <br> 63
        <br> 64 <br> 65 <br> 66 <br> 67 <br> 68 <br> 69 <br> 70 <br> 71 <br> 72 <br> 73 <br> 74 <br> 75 <br> 76 <br> 77 <br> 78 <br> 79 <br> 80 <br> 81 <br> 82 <br> 83 <br> 84 <br> 85 <br> 86 <br> 87 <br> 88 <br> 89 <br> 90 <br> 91 <br> 92 <br> 93 <br>        94 <br> 95 <br> 96 <br> 97 <br> 98 <br> 99 <br> 100 <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the code in SO snippet so that the issue can be reproduced for analysis.

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman sir its already in snippet , there's even a option to run code snippet if you open in dekstop mode

Comment: Ah!! okay.. I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.model` class will give you desire result.

```js
$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
      box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .pic {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 35%;
  }
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        1 <br> 2 <br> 3 <br> 4 <br> 5 <br> 6 <br> 7 <br> 8 <br> 9 <br> 10 <br> 11 <br> 12 <br> 13 <br> 14 <br> 15 <br> 16 <br> 17 <br> 18 <br> 19 <br> 20 <br> 21 <br> 22 <br> 23 <br> 24 <br> 25 <br> 26 <br> 27 <br> 28 <br> 29 <br> 30 <br> 31 <br> 32 <br>        33 <br> 34 <br> 35 <br> 36 <br> 37 <br> 38 <br> 39 <br> 40 <br> 41 <br> 42 <br> 43 <br> 44 <br> 45 <br> 46 <br> 47 <br> 48 <br> 49 <br> 50 <br> 51 <br> 52 <br> 53 <br> 54 <br> 55 <br> 56 <br> 57 <br> 58 <br> 59 <br> 60 <br> 61 <br> 62 <br> 63
        <br> 64 <br> 65 <br> 66 <br> 67 <br> 68 <br> 69 <br> 70 <br> 71 <br> 72 <br> 73 <br> 74 <br> 75 <br> 76 <br> 77 <br> 78 <br> 79 <br> 80 <br> 81 <br> 82 <br> 83 <br> 84 <br> 85 <br> 86 <br> 87 <br> 88 <br> 89 <br> 90 <br> 91 <br> 92 <br> 93 <br>        94 <br> 95 <br> 96 <br> 97 <br> 98 <br> 99 <br> 100 <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because, you have applied 100% height to your `.modal` element and also applied 100px padding on top for the same. One solution is to apply `box-sizing: border-box` to `.modal` or try height and padding in percentage so that the sum wont exceed 100% or rather than applying height, try setting bottom offset

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , i understood the issue.  Fixed it

Comment: Cheers Badal sir :)